# Kubernetes commands are not running inside the Jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVnxW.png)I have deployed Jenkins container inside the k8s cluster successfuly but I can't able to execute "kubectl get pod -A" where as kubectl also installed inside the Jenkins container. How can I run k8s command inside the Jenkins container so I can able to apply CI/CD for k8s.
Below is the errors when I run k8s command inside the Jenkins container which is running inside the k8s pod.

Comment: I have also uploaded a screenshot of errors which I am currently facing.

Comment: kubectl need ".kube" directory with credentials for access to the cluster. Simple install kubectl is not enough.

Comment: Hello @HassanShamshir Please remove the screenshots from your question and post the text instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the cluster role binding for the service account jenkins.

1. Create a file with the name sa.yaml and add below content in it

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
```

2. Create the role binding using the command.

```
kubectl apply -f sa.yaml
```