# Issues running kubectl from Jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have deployed jenkins on the kubernetes cluster using helmchart by following this:

https://octopus.com/blog/jenkins-helm-install-guide

I have the pods and services running in the cluster. I was trying to create a pipeline to run some kubectl commands. It is failing with below error:

java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "kubectl": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)

I thought that it has something to do with the Kubernetes CLI plugin for jenkins and raised an issue here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-cli-plugin/issues/108

I have been advised to install kubectl inside jenkins pod.

I have the jenkins pod already running (deployed using helmchart). I have been seeing options to include the kubectl image binary as part of the dockerfile. But, I have used the helmcharts and not sure if I have to luxury to edit and deploy the pod to add the kubectl.

Can you please help with your inputs to resolve this? IS there any steps/documentation that explain how to install kubectl on the running pod? Really appreciate your inputs as this issue stopped one of my critical projects. Thanks in advance.

I tried setting the rolebinding for the jenkins service account as mentioned here:

[Kubernetes commands are not running inside the Jenkins container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103431/kubernetes-commands-are-not-running-inside-the-jenkins-container)

I haven't installed kubectl inside pod yet. Please help.

Jenkins pipeline:

```
kubeconfig(credentialsId: 'kube-config', serverUrl: '')
sh 'kubectl get all --all-namespaces'
```

(attached the pod/service details for jenkins)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZSdp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Despite  jenkins agent pod is runinng inside kubernetes cluster, jenkins agent container itself does not have `kubectl` utility installed.

You may have to build your own jenkins agent docker image, install all the tools you need and then use it instead of the default jenkins agent.

Dockerfile for your custom agent may contain lines like this:

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:4.11-1-jdk11

USER root

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" \
    && chmod 755 kubectl \
    && mv kubectl /bin

USER jenkins
```

and in your helm values.yaml instead of default

```
agent:
  image: "jenkins/inbound-agent"
  tag: "4.11.2-4"
```

you may set

```
agent:
  image: "your-dockerhub-repo/custom-jenkins-agent"
  tag: "1.0.0-your-version"
```

Comment: Sure Ludenus. Sorry for the delayed response. Really appreciate your inputs. Yeah I am planning to use the other jenkins images to see if I can resolve this issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am running Jenkins in a docker container:

```
docker run --privileged -d --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home --network minikube jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I faced the same problems when starting a jenkins job, so to solve it, I added `-v /usr/local/bin/kubectl:/usr/local/bin/kubectl` to my command

```
docker run --privileged -d --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /usr/local/bin/kubectl:/usr/local/bin/kubectl -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home --network minikube jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

So, I suggest trying to **mount "/usr/local/bin/kubectl"** to your jenkins pod.